# Aerospike Python Documentation - Incorrect Syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, database, nosql, aerospike

I'm trying to follow Aerospike's Python Documentation [here](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/usage/query/query.html), but  it seems that it has a syntax error?

```py
def print_result((key, metadata, record)):
    print(key, metadata, record)
```

Anyone who has a better idea on how to query data using Python with Aerospike?

Comment: BTW, typically it is useful to share the reported error when asking how to resolve that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there was an error when translating this doc from python 2 to python 3. Now it is invalid for both. I've raised the issue to the maintainer when [you posted this issue on our forums](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/syntax-error-on-python-documentation/6878).

For python 2, you only need to remove the parenthesis around the print statement or import `print_function` from `__future__`.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def print_result((key, metadata, record)):
    print(key, metadata, record)
```

Python 3 removed support for tuple parameter unpacking ([PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)). So to fix this for python 3 you just need to remove the tuple parameter unpacking:

```
def print_result(args):
    key, metadata, record = *args
    print(key, metadata, record)
```

Comment: This works. I didn't see a reply on the forum, that's why i posted here. Sorry. Thanks.